# Submit POST form from a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a form that I would like to submit (POST) when a function is called outside the form and without a button (It works with a button).

I have tried to use this: `document.getElementById('liked').submit();`

But then it just pastes this into the url: http://localhost:3000/?postId=108&userId=1

I have tried to put `method="post"` in the form tag, but then it says “CANNOT POST”

The post is done with Axios.

Besides that, I would like it to NOT reload the page/component

This is my form:

```
<form id="liked" name="liked" onSubmit={handlePost}>
  <input hidden name="postId" id="postId" value={product.id} />
  <input hidden name="userId" id="userId" value={currentUser.id} />
</form>;
```

This is my callback that call the Axios post function:

```
const handlePost = useCallback((event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    context.postBookmark(event.target);
  });
```

This is where I would like the form to be submitted:

```
const onSwipe = (direction) => {
    if (direction == "right") {
      // SUBMIT HERE
      document.getElementById("liked").submit();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ideally, you'd have a single function that you can call that would perform the submit, that doesn't rely on the event target. You could then call that function when you want to submit the data, from whatever event you like.

Answer (score 3):

When you call the `submit()` method of the form it **directly** submits the form.

It does not trigger a `submit` event. The submit handler won't be called. `preventDefault` will not be called. `context.postBookmark` will not be called.

If  you want to call `context.postBookmark` from outside the form, then just do it directly without starting a regular form submission.

```
context.postBookmark(document.getElementById("liked"));
```

---

Aside: Direct DOM access is not recommended with using React. Instead use [a reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) or (better) store the data in the state and read it from there).